# Light theme for search suggestions with toolbar

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-appcompat

I've implemented recent search suggestions for my app and it works fine. But the suggestions are shown in dark theme and I want it to be in light theme.

[image]

I did try a lot suggestions available in stackoverflow and could not find success.

Any help will be highly appreciated.